# Viewpager PageScrollStateChanged called multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I was wondering if it's normal that PageScrollStateChanged, an event of a ViewPager, is called 3 times when swiping the viewpager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes that is the normal behavior. meanings of the arg0 at 3 times as follows.

```
   1 for begins dragging
   2 is when the pager is automatically settling to the current page
   0 fully stopped/idle.
```

you can write your code inside    " if(arg0==1) " block, if you want to do execute code only if it is scrolling.